# printing space in android using java

Tags: android

I want to print space in a text View in append but it does not work.

```js
do {
  //bustxt.setTextColor(fff2f2);
  //bustxt.setText("");
  int bussize, routesize, j;

  //ruttxt.setText("");
  route = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("ROUTE"));
  routesize = route.length();

  ruttxt.append("Route " + i + ":\n" + route + "\n\n");
  k++;
  ruttxt.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF4848"));

  bus = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("BUS"));
  bussize = bus.length();

  bustxt.append("Bus " + i + ":\n" + bus + "\n\n");
  bustxt.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF4848"));

  for (j = 1; j <= (routesize - bussize); j++) {
    bustxt.append(".");
  }

  i++;

} while (cursor.moveToNext() != false);
```

here routesize and bussize are the number of space which I want to print. How can I solve this problem easily. Please inform me with a code sample.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the unicode character for whitespace \u0020

```
bustxt.append(String.valueOf(\u0020));
```